# Convert BigQuery rows to array of JSON

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I wan to convert all the rows of BigQuery query output to an array of JSON.
For example: I want to convert the following output rows

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| ex1a | ex1b |
| ex2a | ex2b |

Convert this to the following JSON:

````
           { 
             "Col1":"ex1a",
             "Col2":"ex1b"
            },
            {
             "Col1":"ex2a",
             "Col2":"ex2b"
            }
    ]```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select format('[%s]', string_agg(to_json_string(t)))
from your_table t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Another option (with same output) is

```
select to_json_string(array_agg(t))
from your_table t
```